# TypeORM postgres db, parametrized queries adding quotes and failing query

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to use TypeORM to execute a CREATE SCHEMA statement using a parametrized query, to avoid SQL injection, like below:

```
const schema_name: string = 'myschema';
await getManager()
    .query(
        `create schema if not exists $1
      authorization current_user;`,
        [schema_name],
    )
```

The issue seems to be that the final query adds single quotes around the parameter, so the final query becomes

```
create schema if not exists 'myschema'
          authorization current_user;
```

Is there a way to add in the parameter with no quotes so that the statement will look like this and be valid:

```
create schema if not exists myschema
          authorization current_user;
```

Also, I could not find any documentation on how to get the final query (with parameters filled in) to show anywhere to see what was actually happening when the parameter was inserted. If there is a way to get the complete query before/during/after the execution that would be great as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameterized query syntax depends on what driver you used, for example:

- mysql

```
await getEntityManager().query('SELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE category = ?', [ 'fitness'])
```

- postgresql

```
await getEntityManager().query( `SELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE "category" = $1 `;, [ 'fitness'])
```

According to https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/881, it seems no way to escape table name in parameterized query

Comment: I am using postgresql, as stated in the title of the question. I had come across the issue thread you linked before, didn't make the connection about the table names, but was also hoping there was a way around the issue perhaps specific for create statements. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, just realized also that while tablenames cannot be escaped easily (without some hacky string manipulation), is the same true for schemanames?

Comment: @SallyLee sorry, I can not give you a confident answer about whether same or not with   schemanames.According https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/881, I guess they have same behaviors