# How to union two tables in typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to union two tables in typeorm.

First version:
I crated sql raw queries, for each table

```
    const tableUn = this.tableUnion.createQueryBuilder('tu')
        .select('id')
        .addSelect('description', 'name')
        .getQuery();

    const tableTg = this.tags.createQueryBuilder('tg')
        .select(['id', 'name'])
        .getQuery();
```

After create slq raw query with union:

```
const tags = await entityManager.query(`${ tableUn } UNION ${ tableTg }`);
```

Create new entity and insert received data to it.

```
const createdEntity = entityManager.create(TableUnion, tags);
```

In the end, I wanted use this entity in connection query builder, but it doesn't work

```
      const result = await connection.createQueryBuilder()
          .from(createdEntity, 'cE')
          .getRawMany();
```

Second version:

```
    const a = connection
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('*')
        .from(qb => qb
            .from(TableUnion, 'tu')
            .select('id')
            .addSelect('description', 'tu.name'),
            'ttu'
        )
        .addFrom(qb => qb
            .from(TagsEntity, 'tg')
            .select('id')
            .addSelect('tg.name'),
            'ttg'
        )
```

It created table with data and columns from two tables, but doesn't connect

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution for myself.

```js
// two queries with different parameters from the same table
const query1WithParams = repo.createQueryBuilder("table1")
.select("table1.id")
.where("table1.id = :input_id" , { input_id : 5 })
.getQueryAndParameters();

const query2WithParams = repo.createQueryBuilder("table1")
.select("table1.id")
.where("table1.id = :input_id" , { input_id : 10 })
.getQueryAndParameters();
```

Remember if you don't have any parameters it's better to use `.getQuery()` instead of `.getQueryAndParameters()`.
So let me explain a problem may you'll encounter.
if you don't have parameters everything is fine and you can use your queries without any preparation. but if you have parameters like my example at the top you have to change the parameters placeholders yourself to avoid collision of them.

If you take look at the result queries of both these, you would see both of them have the exact `WHERE` clause

```
-- Result of query1WithParams and the parameter must be 5
WHERE "table1"."id" > $1

-- Result of query2WithParams and the parameter must be 10
WHERE "table1"."id" > $1
```

As you see we have one placeholder for two values (`5`,) and it doesn't work so we have to change one of them to `$2`
(different databases have their own parameter format for parameters and this example is about `Postgres`. if you want to know more take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63976223/13358783).)
You can change one of them like this :

```js
const [query2, params2] = query2WithParams
const correct_query2 = query.replace("$1", "$2")
```

And after that, you must merge the parameters array into one **(The order of them is important)**

```js
const [query1, params1] = query1WithParams
const correct_params = [...params1, ...params2]
```

And now you are ready to use them as input queries for the union.

```js
const result = await repo.manager.query(
"(" + query1 +")" + "UNION" + "(" + correct_query2 +")",
correct_params
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way I've found to handle unions in a querybuilder is to construct your own UNION SQL string containing the queries from other query builders and then use that in a [FROM subquery](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#using-subqueries) of a new querybuilder.

Here's a way to do that given an array of query builders

```js
// Assume we have an array of query builders that all select column1 and column2
const queryBuilders: SelectQueryBuilder<unknown>[]

const sqlQueries = queryBuilders.map((b) => b.getQuery());

// Merge all the parameters from the other queries into a single object. You'll need to make sure that all your parameters have unique names
const sqlParameters = queryBuilders
  .map((b) => b.getParameters())
  .reduce((prev, curr) => ({ ...prev, ...curr }), {});

// Join all your queries into a single SQL string
const unionedQuery = '(' + sqlQueries.join(') UNION (') + ')';

// Create a new querybuilder with the joined SQL string as a FROM subquery
const unionQueryBuilder: SelectQueryBuilder<unknown> = dataSource
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select('column1, column2')
  .from(`(${unionedQuery})`, 'combined_queries_alias')
  .setParameters(sqlParameters);
```

This solution doesn't appear to run into the parameter collision problem described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74839534/1972453). I believe that's because TypeORM takes care of re-numbering parameters when you use the combined SQL in a querybuilder but it doesn't when you use it directly in a query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Common table expressions](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#common-table-expressions) to achieve this. The addCommonTableExpression() method accepts a string where you can place your UNION query. It could look something like this:

```
await connection.createQueryBuilder()
.select()
.addCommonTableExpression(
  `SELECT tu.id AS id, tu.description as description, tu.name as name
   FROM table_union tu
   UNION ALL
   SELECT tg.id, null as description, tg.name as name
   FROM tags tg`,
  'cte'
)
.getMany();
```

Answer (score -4):

I think you could do the following:

```
   const tableUn = this.tableUnion.createQueryBuilder('tu')
  .select('id')
  .addSelect('description', 'name')
  .getRawMany();
    
  const tableTg = this.tags.createQueryBuilder('tg')
  .select(['id', 'name'])
  .getRawMany();

   return tableUn.concat(tableTg)
```