# I tried to convert this SQL query to TypeORM?

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I tried to convert this sql query to TypeORM, but I didn't. And I wanna help from stackoverflow communities.

SQL Query

```
SELECT s.status, COUNT(o.order_status) as count
FROM (SELECT 'pending' as status
      UNION
      SELECT 'pendingPayment'
      UNION
      SELECT 'processingPayment'
      UNION
      SELECT 'processing'
      UNION
      SELECT 'shipping') s
LEFT JOIN `order` o ON s.status = o.order_status
GROUP BY s.status
```

Query Result

| status | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Pending | 0 |
| pendingPayment | 0 |
| processing | 0 |
| processingPayment | 0 |
| shipping | 0 |

order_status = enum["pending", "pendingPayment", "processingPayment", "processing", "shipping"]

Order table has

- order_id
- order_number
- order_status
- order_currency
- sub_total
- discount_total
- shipping_total
- total_tax
- total_price
- payment_method
- customer_ip_address
- customer_user_agent
- customer_note
- cancellation_reason
- estimated_arrival_date
- date_completed
- date_created
- date_updated
- promoCodePromoId
- customerCustomerId
- shippingAddressShippingId

I tried to convert this sql query to TypeORM

Comment: I have had the same issue and you can read about my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74839534/13358783